# how to show ram used by an application

Tags: android, ram

I have a list in my application that shows the running apps and also i want to show used ram by the running application . (other apps)

also i don't want to use this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setClassName("com.android.settings",  "com.android.settings.RunningServices");
```

please give me a solution . thank you!

Comment: check if [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android)